# Get-ChildItem on UNC path does not work with PS7.2

Tags: powershell

Whenever I run this command

`Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath \\?\UNC\myserver\Dados01\Marketing`

I get the expected behaviour on PS5.1, but on PS7.2 it lists the content of my local C:\ drive instead.

If I remove the UNC prefix, it works fine, but I may get PathTooLongExceptions, so this is not a solution.
Is this a known bug of PS7 ?

Comment: take a look [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10805)

Comment: okay, so I guess I can get rid of the \\?\ prefix since PS7 supports long file paths by default. Thanks for clearing that up !